# default_scope with :include option rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, upgrade, default-scope

i am upgrading a rails3 app to 3.2.6
  i have some issues with the deprecated default_scope with options.

I have a couple of models Campaigns and Sites with many-many relationship through campaign_sites.

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :campaign_sites, :dependent => :destroy
  ....
end

class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :campaign_sites, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :campaigns, :through => :campaign_sites
  ...
end

class CampaignSite < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :include => [:campaign, :site], :order => :'sites.name' 
  belongs_to :campaign, :touch => true
  belongs_to :site, :touch => true
  ...
end
```

This is working fine with rails 3.0.10 but after upgrading to 3.2.6 i am getting the following mysql error with this line.

```
default_scope :include => [:campaign, :site], :order => :'sites.name'

Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'sites.name' in 'order clause': SELECT `campaigns`.* FROM`campaigns` INNER JOIN `campaign_sites` ON `campaigns`.`id` = `campaign_sites`.`campaign_id` WHERE `campaign_sites`.`site_id` = 11377 ORDER BY campaigns.name, sites.name
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a change to how the include is working between 3.0.10 and 3.2.6. Instead of making a single query, it's now making multiple queries to do the eager loading. I would just stick a `joins` option in there so it's explicitly joining with the sites table:

```
default_scope :include => [:campaign, :site], :order => :'sites.name', :joins => :sites
```

Comment: I tried with `:include` in 3.2.6 and it works. Most likely, there is a problem with the DB structure.

Comment: @WawaLoo, i tried even with :joins => :sites, but it didn't worked. Can you provide more info about db structure you are talking about?

Comment: Does it still produce the same SQL?

Comment: @Beerlington, yes it produced exactly the same sql query.